# Load same tab of tabbed panel on form submission

Tags: jquery, struts2

Using Struts2 and JQuery. Have tabbed panel with each form with a submit   button.

On submit it forwards to the jsp different from the tabbed panel. 
My requirement is 
1. tab1 ---- > on submit stay on tab1
2. tab2 -----> on submit move to next tab

How to achieve this? I tried the below but it redirects to a jsp off tabbed panel.

```
<s:url var="tab1Url" action="tab1Action"/>
<s:url var="tab2Url" action="tab2Action"/>

<sj:tabbedpanel id="remotetabs" selectedTab="0" show="true" hide="'fade'" collapsible="true" sortable="true" useSelectedTabCookie="true">
    <sj:tab id="tab1" href="%{tab1Url}" key="label.tab1" />
    <sj:tab id="tab2" href="%{tab2Url}" key="label.tab2"/>
</sj:tabbedpanel>
```

tab1.jsp  --- is as below

```
<s:form action="saveCompInfo" method="post" validate="true" >
    <s:textfield name="compName" key="label.compNumber"/>
    <s:textfield name="compDescription" key="label.compDescription"/>
    <s:submit value="save"></s:submit>
</s:form>
```

struts.xml

```
<action name="tab1Action" class="xxx.CompanyAction">
    <result>/jsp/createCompanyPanel.jsp</result>                      
    <result name="input">tab1Action</result>
</action>
<action name="saveCompInfo" class="xxx.CompanyAction" method="saveCompany">
    <result>/jsp/createCompanyPanel.jsp</result> 
    <result name="input">tab1Action</resul
</action>
<action name="tab2Action" class="xxx.CreateDepartmentsAction">
    <result>/jsp/createDepartmentPanel.jsp</result> 
    <result name="input">tab2Action</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Use js on page load to set desired tab.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form the page is reloaded and the current tab of the panel becomes having the initial setting. That shouldn't happen if you submit the form via Ajax.

```xml
<s:form action="saveCompInfo" method="post" validate="true" >
    <s:textfield name="compName" key="label.compNumber"/>
    <s:textfield name="compDescription" key="label.compDescription"/>
    <sj:submit value="save"/>
</s:form>
```